# what is the purpase of the command rsync -rvzh

Tags: bash

im trying to understand what this two command doing:

```
config=$(date +%s)
rsync -rvzh $1 /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/target > /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config
```

this line appears in a bigger script - `script.sh` looking like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

config=$(date +%s)
rsync -rvzh $1 /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/target > /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config

countC=0
countS=`wc -l /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`
let countS--
let countS--
let countS--

while read LINEC #read line
do  
    if [ "$countC" -gt 0 ]; then
        if [ "$countC" -lt "$countS" ]; then

            FILENAME="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/target/"$LINEC
            count=0
            countW=0

            while read LINE
            do
                for word in $LINE;
                do 
                    echo "INSERT INTO data_mining.data (word, line, numWordLine, file) VALUES ('$word', '$count', '$countW', '$FILENAME');" >> /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/query
                    mysql -u root -Alaba1515< /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/query
                    echo > /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/query
                    let countW++
                done
                countW=0
                let count++
            done < $FILENAME
            count=0

            rm -f /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/query
            rm -f /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config

        fi
    fi
    let countC++
done < /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config #finish while
```

i was able to find lots of documentary about rsync and what it is doing but i don't understand whats the rest of the command do. any help please?

Comment: http://explainshell.com/ is your friend.

Comment: also, there's a lot of awful in this script. For instance, if a line contains `*`, then `for word in $LINE` would be looking at files in the current directory where it's run. Should be rewritten to use `read -a`. Also, it would be trivial to craft contents which would escape their quotes and perform a SQL injection attack against the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first command assigns the current time (in seconds since epoch) to the shell variable `config`.  For example:

```
$ config=$(date +%s)
$ echo $config
1446506996
```

`rsync` is a file copying utility.  The second command thus makes a backup copy of the directory listed in argument 1 (referred to as `$1`).  The backup copy is placed in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/target`.  A log file of what was copied is saved in `var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config`:

```
rsync -rvzh $1 /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/target > /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/DataMining/$config
```

The `rsync` options mean:

- `-r` tells rsync to copy files diving recursively into subdirectories
- `-v` tells it to be verbose so that it shows what is copied.
- `-z` tells it to compress files during their transfer from one location to the other.
- `-h` tells it to show any numbers in the output in human-readable format.

Note that because `$1` is not inside double-quotes, this script will fail if the name of directory `$1` contains whitespace.